# List of calls - get number of calls per person

Tags: mysql

I have a list of calls (see image).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB0YC.jpg

What I would like to do is to count the number of calls per employee per day.

I know that I can get the calls per day in the entire team with this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT (DATE(time_of_call)) AS unique_date, 
    COUNT(*) AS amount 
FROM manual_calls 
GROUP BY unique_date 
ORDER BY unique_date ASC here
```

However, I am not sure how to get the calls per person. Thank you already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Date(unique_date) as unique_date, 
   Employee, 
   Count(*) as CallsPerDay
From Manual_Calls
Group By unique_date, Employee

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply! So Group_By was the key :-)